# Examples containing all generality

Tags: soft-question, examples-counterexamples, intuition

[As Paul Halmos said](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk//Quotations/Halmos.html):

> ...the source of all great mathematics is the special case, the concrete example. **It is frequent in mathematics that every instance of a concept of seemingly great generality is in essence the same as a small and concrete special case.**

This quote is similar to one of Hilbert:

> The art of doing mathematics consists in finding that special case which contains all the germs of generality.

I want to know: What are some good examples of special cases containing all generality?

One answer per post. Community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, the theory for the classification of finite-dimensional complex simple Lie algebras and their linear representations is to a large extend given by understanding the theory for the special case of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$.